# Install cPanel on Rackspace Cloud servers

Tags: cloud-computing, rackspace-cloud

I'm on Rackspace cloud servers, and I'm trying to install cPanel

It went through the whole process and its telling me that I need to change my hostname
to a fully qualified domain name

I tried setting the hostname to some random domains to see if it'd work, but it didn't

Perharps if some of you know, what fully qualified domain they might be talking about, It would be great if you can explain.

BTW, I didn't even register any domain (or needed to) for the server process or to get the cPanel license, so I'm really confused as to what domain they're telling me to put in for the hostname

Comment: If you type "hostname" into the shell, what do you get?  Have you tried using that name?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you haven't configured any other hostname or DNS records:

In the Rackspace Cloud management portal, go to the config section for that cloud server.  Go to the DNS tab, and try using the hostname displayed at the bottom in the Reverse DNS Management section.  It will be something like `184-106-140-148.static.cloud-ips.com`.

Comment: I changed the hostname to what you suggested and still can't get it to work. I think cPanel wants something else, I'm not sure.

Comment: I installed plesk now. Plesk seems a lot easier to install.